# How to proccess blocking time of a simulated queue in java for an M/M/2 system?

Tags: java, arrays, math, queue, simulation

hello guys for simulating the queue blocking time for an M/M/1 I came up with this very solution, but it is not Object-oriented  unfortunately, also the problem is I want to simulate it with M/M/2 system,for instance I initialized lambda with 19 and mu with 20 just for ease up the calculation any solution, hint, code example will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int MAX_ENTITY = 100000;
        final int SYSTEM_CAPACITY = 5;
        final int BUSY = 1;
        final int IDLE = 0;
        double lambda = 19, mu = 20;
        int blocked = 0;
        int queue_length = 0;
        int server_state = IDLE;
        int entity = 0;
        double next_av = getArivalRand(lambda);
        double next_dp = next_av + getDeparturedRand(lambda);
        while (entity <= MAX_ENTITY) {
            //Arrival
            if (next_av <= next_dp) {
                entity++;
                if (server_state == IDLE) {
                    server_state = BUSY;
                } else if (queue_length < SYSTEM_CAPACITY - 1) {
                    queue_length++;
                } else {
                    blocked++;
                }
                next_av += getArivalRand(lambda);
            } // Departure
            else if (queue_length > 0) {
                queue_length--;
                next_dp = next_dp + getDeparturedRand(mu);
            } else {
                server_state = IDLE;
                next_dp = next_av + getDeparturedRand(mu);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Blocked Etity:" + blocked + "\n");
    }

    public static double getArivalRand(double lambda) {
        return -1 / lambda * Math.log(1 - Math.random());
    }

    public static double getDeparturedRand(double mu) {
        return -1 / mu * Math.log(1 - Math.random());
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory) if u don't know about the queue theory

Comment: please be polite, it indicates number of servers, read here for more info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue

Comment: It was just a silly joke. You should edit the link into your question.

Comment: What, specifically, is your question?  I.e., what does your code do that it shouldn't, or not do that it should?

Comment: @pjs as I described, I implemented it in M/M/1 order I want to achieve M/M/2, also with OOP principles, I see no reason for flag down Please

Comment: @Michael thank you I edited it, please upvote it so that I can get the answer more quickly

Comment: @zoejane I'm not the downvoter, I just asked for clarification.  You still haven't explained what your code is doing that it shouldn't, or not doing that it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh boy you're code needs serious refactoring in order to achieve `M/M/2`.
I created a gist file [here](https://gist.github.com/shaheenzahedi/a002935d5c632b2149b795e248b4a548) which I think implements what you wanted,
In the gist file I created  a  `Dispatcher` class for balancing two queues in two servers and also I've simulated it with two seeds, it is much more Object-Oriented approach,

> here is an example code from gist file which is for balancing load of
>   the tasks

```
if (server1.getQueueLength() < server2.getQueueLength()) 
   currentServer = server1;
else if (server1.getQueueLength() > server2.getQueueLength()) 
   currentServer = server2;
else if (currentServer == server1) 
   currentServer = server2;
else 
   currentServer = server1;
```